# read out of range during install of kubuntu

Tags: grub2, system-installation, kubuntu

I would like to install kubuntu on my laptop. However when I boot from the USB stick it doesnt matter what option I choose from the grub menu it displays.

```
error: read out of range
error: you need to start the kernel first
```

I am using Balena Etcher to flash the USB, it does seem to verify it. I want to install kubuntu 20.04.4 on dualboot with windows 11.
I also verified the SHA Checksum of the download.

Comment: Hello. When you downloaded the ISO and before you made the live media did you verify the ISO? What tool did you use to make the live media? Seems you may also have not given all info, Is this dual booted? What version of kUbuntu are you working with?

Comment: @David I am using Balena Etcher to flash the USB, it does seem to verify it. I want to install kubuntu 20.04.4 on dualboot with windows 11.

Comment: Does seem to verify or does?

Comment: @TheFibonacciEffect Balena Etcher can't verify file corruption. It should be obvious it can only compare the original ISO contents with what it wrote in the USB. What you need to verify is the ISO *before* burning it.

Comment: Oh, yes. I did not verify the download, I dont know yet how to do that. I tried downloading the file again though.

Comment: Now I verified that the SHA256 sum matches the one on https://kubuntu.org/alternative-downloads/

Comment: In my experience the most likely cause for the error you mention is (1) a invalid ISO; rare but it can occur & you appear to have that covered, or far more likely (2) an invalid write to your installation media; thus the bad pointer that goes outside of the device's-range...  so was this verified??  The software re-verify doesn't mean much; unless it's capable of writing the ISO you're using as it'll verify correctly on ISOs it cannot write too  (is your software up-to-date?).  I'd boot the thumb-drive on another device (even two; one of same type) & see if verification occurs there of media.

Comment: @guiverc I hope balena etcher is up to date as I installed it last week. It does verify it in the last step, I don't know what it does though. I flashed the medium more than 10 times. I will try to boot it on another device, when I get the chance.

Comment: What you can also do is try a different program to make the USB-stick (like Ventoy or Rufus) and try that. Is the stick faulty, then use a different one.

Comment: It was the USB stick. I think Windows did not format it correctly for some reason. It's a bit wierd that Etcher still said it was okay.